# PHP - How can i select multiple check boxes and show all the values from the selected check boxes?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one html table with all the values from a specific table, and i want to put an update button to update specific rows

And i want to update those rows using checkboxes.

The user just need to check the selectboxes and click at a button, and this button will display all the information from the rows that were selected.

I have here a bit of code that i created, but i just can read the last selected box value.

I'm using MVC structure, but with my own rules.

Here the model, I created the function inside the model:

```
$editjo_query = ("SELECT * FROM my_table");

$print_editjo = db_array($editjo_query, 'a+'); //this is a function that i created to    select, ignore please

if(!empty($_POST['editcheck'])){

    $editcheckbox = $_POST['editcheck'];
    $countCheckedit = count($_POST['editcheck']);

    for($i=0;$i<$countCheckedit;$i++) {
        $edit_id = $editcheckbox[$i];

        $editjo_query = ("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=$edit_id");

        $print_editjo = db_array($editjo_query, 'a+'); //this is a function that i created to select, ignore please
     }
}
```

And this function is being called at the view

```
function editjoview($print_editjo){
     foreach($print_editjo as $check){
        echo $check['id'];
     }
}
```

Comment: can post your html code?

Comment: why do you need an html code? I just want to get the value from the checked boxes, you dont need to know the html code, i just cited the html to explain how i'm doing everything, i just want to read the checkboxes values multiple times.

Comment: did your check box name like this? name='checkbox[]'?

Comment: yes, name='editcheck[]'

Comment: try to use foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are always writing to `$print_editjo` with `$print_editjo = db_array($editjo_query, 'a+');` and you you do not process it. So in ever for loop you overwrite it, leaving you with the last entry.
Try this:

```
$print_editjo = array();
for($i=0;$i<$countCheckedit;$i++) {
  $edit_id = $editcheckbox[$i];
  $editjo_query = ("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=$edit_id");
  $print_editjo[] = db_array($editjo_query, 'a+');
}
```

and in your view, iterate over the array `$print_editjo` rather than just having `$print_editjo` as the last entry.

Note: If you would add how exactly the function in your view is called, the help could be more precise.